# Normalizer fatal error with XAMPP and PHP 5.4.4

Tags: php, xampp

When I use the PHP class `Normalizer` (e.g. `\Normalizer::normalize($string, Normalizer::FORM_KD);`) in my class `Text.php` in custom namespace `Utils`, I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Utils\Normalizer' not found 
in C:\xampp\htdocs\MyProject\src\Utils\text.php on line 380
```

My project runs under **XAMPP** with **PHP 5.4.4**. I know also that:

- `Normalizer` should work since **PHP 5 >= 5.3.0**.
- The extension `php_intl.dll` is enabled in my `php.ini`
  file.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the leading *backslash* In `Normalizer::FORM_KD` when calling `\Normalizer::normalize($string, Normalizer::FORM_KD)` notice you only used one backslash in front of the class name, but not when you're using the **class constant**.

In PHP when you declare or import a namespace you are telling PHP to alias all of your function, class/interface, and constant names to your namespace.

So the following code would issue a similar fatal error...

```
<?php
namespace foo;

var_dump(DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2012-12-06'));
```

The above code would issue an error of `PHP Fatal error: Class 'foo\DateTime' not found in /testfile.php on line 4`

To fix this make sure you always call those functions/classes/interfaces/constants which are not declared in your namespace/alias to the global namespace.

```
<?php
namespace foo;
/* Notice the leading backslash infront of DateTime*/
var_dump(\DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d','2012-12-06'));
```